# How to integrate payment gateway Paytm using swift in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, paytm

I am developing project for paying bills through app, for that I need to add payment gateway paytm in project? But I don't know how to add. I have searched but I didn't find any tutorial to learn.

Anyone, please help me.

Comment: Take a look at Cocoapods.

Comment: follow their documentation, they must have some

Comment: @valosip thank u, may i know which Cocoapods.. can you share any link regarding paytm

Comment: Take a look at Ninjas link. It’s their official SDK and write up. I’d follow that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not expert in how to implement payment gateway but you can follow this example https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/ios-sdk/

Comment: thank you for sharing the link.. i will try to follow